# How to convert unicode to accented character in Python string

Tags: python, unicode

I have a list of soccer players' names but can't get the names with accented characters to print properly. I've looked at numerous StackOverflow posts, but can't seem to find a solution that works.

Right now, I'm stuck with the output `Alexis S\u00e1nchez`, when I want `Alexis Sánchez`.

Comment: What version of python, what operating system, and please include some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Python 3.x:

```
>>> print(bytes('Alexis S\\u00e1nchez', 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape'))
Alexis Sánchez
```

And Python 2.x:

```
>>> print("Alexis S\\u00e1nchez".decode("unicode-escape"))
Alexis Sánchez
```